# Titanium not showing ipad 7.0

Tags: xcode, ipad, titanium

I have `Xcode 5.02` installed on my system and currently doing `ipad app development` using `titanium`.

On creating a project in Xcode it shows all the targets for `ipad ( 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0 )`.
But shows only `6.1 in Titanium`.

can someone share insight on this ?

Comment: What version of Titanium do you have?

Comment: You need to update the Titanium to latest version